# Why is MarkLogic structured word or value query returning more matches than expected?

Tags: marklogic

The purpose of my structured query is to match all documents which have json property with value containing specific substring. So I wrote following code which builds this query with MarkLogic Java API:

```
        var jsonProperty = queryBuilder.jsonProperty("xyz");
        String[] wordOptions = {"case-insensitive", "wildcarded"};
        return queryBuilder.word(jsonProperty, null, wordOptions, 0, "*m-Em i*");
```

For some reason there are more search matches than expected. For example document with "xyz" json property containing "PM-EM 926-2:2020" is matched, but it shouldn't be. What might be the reason behind that problem?

I have also tried:

```
cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:json-property-word-query("xyz", "*m-Em I*", ("case-insensitive", "wildcarded")))
```

and it returns expected matches, but I would rather stick to structured query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you get the same results if you add the "unfiltered" option to your `cts:search()`?

"*m-Em I*" is not a word, it is a phrase that has `-` punctuation char and a leading wildcard and `I*` is a one character word with a trailing wildcard.

So, unless you have the necessary backing indexes, you are likely just searching for "Em" and then with cts:search filtering by default, getting more relevant results.

Take a look at the plan and see what your search winds up becoming:

```
xdmp:plan(cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:json-property-word-query("xyz", "*m-Em I*", ("case-insensitive", "wildcarded"))))
```

And take a look at the difference in results when applying "unfiltered" to the `cts:search`, or by wrapping the search with `xdmp:estimate()` to see what the unfiltered index resolved results would be before applying filtering.

Comment: I have managed to build RawCombinedQuery using Java MarkLogic API. I have included filtering in query by adding `<search-option>filtered</search-option>`. Results seems to be accurate, but for some reason pagination stopped working. I use GenericDocumentManager 'search' method with query and offset supplied as arguments, but every time I incerase offset (which means I query for greater page) 'totalPages' and 'totalSize' are decreasing.  For example if I query for first page, I get 80 totalPages in pagination, but when I query for 10th page i get 61 total pages. Do you know what is the reason?

Comment: totals and pagination are still unfiltered estimates, right? If you go deep enough into the pages, it may wind up filtering things out and then you get a more accurate total and page count. If you perform the same filtered search, how many actual records are there?

Comment: I have just read in Marklogic Java API documentation (Interface Page<T>) that those are indeed estimates. When I perform filtered search, there are 218 records in total. But when I set page size to 10 and page number to 1 then estimate says that there are  787 total records. Is it possible not to get estimates, but real accurate values, despite current page number and page size for filtered searches?